# Circular maps in haskell

Tags: list, haskell, circular-list

I'm tasked with implementing a function that returns the Thue-Morse sequence all the way through. I've done it through primitive recursion but now I have to do it with a circular list (using list comprehension), and it'd have to return this when I call take on it:

```
>take 4 thueSeq
[[0],[0,1],[0,1,1,0],[0,1,1,0,1,0,0,1]]
```

Here's my (horrible) attempt at implementation:

```
> thueSeq = 0: [x | x <- zipWith (mod) (tail thueSeq) [1] ]
```

I'm aware right off the bat that it's wrong (the head is supposed to be [0], not 0) but writing `[0] ++ [0,1] ++ ...` didn't return a list of lists anyway.

My question is, first off, how do I "start off" the list with `[[0],[0,1]]` because from what I've seen with circular lists, they have the base cases and then recurse through. Secondly, my list comprehension is trying to apply `(mod x 1)` to each value, but that'd also be wrong since `[[0,1]]` would turn into `[[0,1,0]]` instead of `[[0,1,1,0]]`. So I'm thinking I have to apply it on every other element in the list (the 1st element, 3rd, 5th, etc.)?

Comment: The direct answer to "how do I 'start off' the list with `[[0],[0,1]]`" is "use `[0] : [0,1] : ...` instead of `[0] ++ [0,1] ++ ...`".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From what I understand...

I have just written a simple flip function that maps 1 to 0 and 0 to 1

```
flipBit 1 = 0
flipBit 0 = 1
```

the function `h` takes a list and joins that list with the flipped version of the list

```
h xs = xs ++ (map flipBit xs)

*Main> h [0]
[0,1]
```

The main function `fseq` takes a list as an argument. It conses the argument into the recursive call

```
fseq xs = xs : fseq (h xs)

*Main> take 4 $ fseq [0]
[[0],[0,1],[0,1,1,0],[0,1,1,0,1,0,0,1]]
```

Haskell provides the function `iterate :: (a -> a) -> a -> [a]` that does exactly this.

We can now wrap this as follows:

```
thue_morse = fseq [0]
```

or using the function `iterate`

```
thue_morse = iterate h [0]
```

both give the result

```
*Main> take 4 thue_morse
[[0],[0,1],[0,1,1,0],[0,1,1,0,1,0,0,1]]
```

If you wanted to use list comprehensions, you could write something like this:

```
h xs = xs ++ (map flipBit xs)
thue_morse = [0] : [ h x | x <- thue_morse]
```